# Git push --all branches that are already on remote, but not un-published local branches

Tags: git

`git push --all` is really handy for pushing a large chain of merges to a remote, but it has the side effect of pushing branches that you may not want pushed out yet, and thus should be avoided in that scenario.

But I really like `--all`.

Is there a way to get `push` to push all branches that are already on that remote but not push branches that the remote does not have?

Answer (score 2):

Try `git push origin :` as it is supposed to only push matching branches on the remote end.

See: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#OPTIONS

> The special refspec : (or +: to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side. This is the default operation mode if no explicit refspec is found (that is neither on the command line nor in any Push line of the corresponding remotes file---see below) and no push.default configuration variable is set.

Answer (score 2):

Direct from [`git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> push.default
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is given on the command line, no refspec is configured in the remote, and no refspec is implied by any of the options given on the command line. Possible values are:

[snip]

> `matching` - push all branches having the same name in both ends. This is for those who prepare all the branches into a publishable shape and then push them out with a single command. It is not appropriate for pushing into a repository shared by multiple users, since locally stalled branches will attempt a non-fast forward push if other users updated the branch.
>
> This is currently the default, but Git 2.0 will change the default to `simple`.

In other words, leave out `--all` but configure `push.default=matching` (which you can do on the command line with a `-c` option, or set in the repository configuration).

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Gack!  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks; It was pretty off-topic and funny, but the actual documentation is appreciated! +1

Comment: The Periodic Table of the Git Configuration, perhaps. :-)